# Why is it not possible to construct a finite state machine in this case?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, state-machine

Why is it not possible to construct a finite state machine that recognizes precisely those sequences in the language

[image]

where the alphabet for A is {0,1}..

I just don't get it why this is not possible...Maybe I am not seeing something as I am new to this.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Not CS theory. try cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The language you posted is not regular, only regular languages (i.e. defined by a regular grammar) can be accepted by a finite state machine.

The reason for this is, non formally, that finite automata can not count because they have a finite number of states. This would be required for comparing i to j in your example.

The construct that will be able to accept your language would be a stackautomaton, because your language is contextfree. 
See the Wikipedia article about chompsky hierarchy[1](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) for additional details.

Comment: Finite automata *can* count, but only modulo a fixed integer. For instance, it's possible to build a finite automaton that captures strings containing an even number of `a`'s and an even number of `b`'s; such an automaton effectively counts modulo 2.

Comment: Of course you are correct, I referred to infinite counting, as the mentioned language requires it.